# Unix looping for Dates

Tags: unix

I have a requirement to run a unix script multiple times for different dates. Script should be executed first for 2017-01-01, then for 2017-02-01 and so on. We are checking the data on a monthly basis. Can someone help me with this please. Thanks.

Comment: This is what the `cron` utility is for (or, if you are using certain versions of Linux, systemd timer units).

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for a scheduled execution. But if I run the script now , then it needs to be executed for Jan 01, Feb 01, march 1st till May 1st. Input values are supposed to be the first day of each month.

Comment: Oh, I think I see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop for iteration, in general. You can generate a sequence of months with `{01..12}` or `seq -w 1 12`, as below:

```
for date in 2017-{01..12}-01; do
    echo Processing data for $date
    # Use $date in some way
done
```

or

```
for month in $(seq -w 1 12); do
    date=2017-$month-01
    echo Processing data for $date
    # use $date in some way
done
```

The first will work in Bash, zsh, and many other shells, but I don’t think is guaranteed to work for any of them; the second should work for any `sh`-like shell.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to run the script for 2 dates. Example , first I need to run the script to find all the records between Jan 1st and Jan 31st, then I need to find records between Feb1st and Feb 28th and so on. I think this is what we need to do with more understanding of the requirement. Is there a way to loop script between 2 dates?

Comment: That’s more complicated, because you need to handle months of differing lengths. The shell doesn’t have an inherent concept of dates, so either you’d need to write a program in a different language to generate the list of dates, you’d need to have a lookup table for how long each month is (taking into account leap years!), or you’d need to have the script fail gracefully if given an invalid date like `2017-04-31` or `2017-02-29`. It might be easier to change the input requirements.

Comment: This is something that I am trying to achieve. instead of copying the steps for multiple dates,is there a way to put below logic in a loop, with a sleep in between  :                                                                 


`#!/bin/bash
for file in '2017-03-01'
do
echo $file
for file1 in '2017-03-31'
do
echo $file1
#run job with $file $file1
echo "Job done"
done
done
sleep 10s
for file in '2017-04-01'
do
echo $file
for file1 in '2017-04-30'
do
echo $file1
#run job with $file $file1
echo "Job done"
done
done`

Comment: Comments here do not support newlines. Could you edit your question to include what you mean? While your at it, can you add the `sh` tag (for the standard Unix shell)?